# How do I gracefully quit out the Sass interactive shell (on Windows)

Tags: shell, sass

I launched the SASS interactive shell, as described at http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interactive_shell

I can't (gracefully) quit.

I've tried:

- quit
- exit
- ^C
- ^.
- ^D
- ^Q

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^D` should do it. What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are on Windows, you might get Ctrl-Z (^Z) to be recognized as the end-of-file marker.

Answer (score 0):

Try ctrl-c or ctrl-d (works on Windows).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error the first time and on my second time installing the Gem i added sudo which worked perfectly

```
Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
```

Just a heads up if that helps.

Comment: My question was about using the interactive shell, not the watcher, but thanks anyhow - its not me down-voting you.